# hide DNN technologies from Wappalyzer

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke

I want to disable detection of Wappalyzer and don't want to show what CMS I am using. Tried to remove "X-Powered-By" but Wappalzer still detects DNN and shows it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is not going to be possible as there are many ways that you can identify a site as being DNN based and you don't know what metrics/method they use.